# Error Showing on image upload in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
        public function set_news($id = 0)
    {
     $this->load->helper('url'); 
    $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
            
     $name=$_FILES["myimage"]["name"];
            
     $folder="./uploads/";
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png");    

    if( in_array($imageFileType, $extensions_arr) )
    {                  
    $data = array(
    'title' => $this->input->post('title'), //         $this->db->escape($this->input->post('title'))
    'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
    'slug' => $slug,
    'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
    'myimage' => $name,
    'user_id' => $this->input->post('user_id'),
    );
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myimage"]["tmp_name"],         "$folder".$_FILES["myimage"]["name"]);    
    }
    //  else
    //   {
    //   echo "<script>alert('Image Error');window.history.back();        </script>";
    // }             
            
    if ($id == 0) {
    //$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
    return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
    } else {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    return $this->db->update('news', $data);
    }
    }
```

this is my controller file

on uploading image it showing error as follows

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: myimage
>
> Filename: models/News_model.php
>
> Line Number: 48
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\web\codeigniter\application\models\News_model.php
> Line: 48
> Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\web\codeigniter\application\controllers\News.php
> Line: 123
> Function: set_news
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\web\codeigniter\index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once

Comment: Show us the result of var_dump($_FILES); .. and make sure that the file input name is myimage.

Comment: You haven't shown us your HTML - do you really have a file upload with name `myimage` in your form?

Comment: <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('news/edit/'.$news_item['id']); ?><div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">New Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="myimage" id="myimage" size="20"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $news_item['myimage'] ?>" />
         </div>
      </div>

Answer (score 0):

Seems you missed to set the input name as "myimage". Here is the complete codeigniter image upload code(As Mention on their Documentation).

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller Code:

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
        }

        public function do_upload()
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                          $uploadData= array(
                         'title' => TITLE,
                        'date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                        'slug' => SLUG,
                        'text' => TEXT,
                        'myimage' => FILE_NAME,
                        'user_id' => USER_ID,
                       );
                      $this->db->insert('mytable', $uploadData);
                        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                }
        }
    }
```